# Jenkins - Powershell plugin - Encoding issue

Tags: git, powershell, jenkins, encoding, jenkins-plugins

I have an issue while using PowerShell Plugin on Jenkins.

**First test :**

When I execute this statement :

```
git --no-pager log [...]
```

I've got this in the console output :

```
29/06/2017 13:38:04 - ééé
```

But, when I try to export it in a file, like this :

```
$log | Out-File out-default.txt
```

OR

```
$log | Out-File out-utf8.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

I've got this problem (with both files : default encoding (UTF-16LE) and UTF-8 encoding) :

```
29/06/2017 13:38:04 - ├®├®├®
```

**Second test :**

```
$log = "ééé"
$log
```

displays in the console output :

```
ǸǸǸ
```

For information, I've added `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in my Jenkins' startup configuration file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is git in your PATH variable?

Comment: @KolobCanyon It is. I can successfully retrieve the log, the only issue is the encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution.

This did the trick :

```
git --no-pager log [...] 
[...]
$log | Out-File myFile.txt -Encoding OEM
```

"é" characters are successfully encoded.